# Move camera with your touch

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
@Override

public void create () {

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    img = new Texture("asd.jpg");

}

@Override

public void render () {

     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);

     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){

       camera.position.x = Gdx.input.getX();

       camera.position.y = Gdx.input.getY();

     }

     camera.update();

     batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

     batch.begin();

     batch.draw(img, 0, 0);

     batch.end();
}
```

also that was my try to do it but it's not working stable.

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        if(!nowOn){
            asd.x = camera.position.x + Gdx.input.getX() * -1;
            asd.y = camera.position.y + Gdx.input.getY();
            camera.position.x = asd.x;
            camera.position.y = asd.y;
        }
    }else{
        if(nowOn){
            nowOn = false;
            asd.x = Gdx.input.getX() + camera.position.x;
            asd.y = Gdx.input.getY() + camera.position.y;
        }
    }
```

i can move camera around the screen with this code but i want that i will move camera with my finger then i'll release my finger and after i have re touched the screen i will keep moving camera where it stayed.

to sum up, i want to roam the large images with my finger.

thanks:)

Comment: In the future, PLEASE take the time to format your code. I've done it for you this time, but it makes it much more readable and people will be more likely to actually read your post. Also, what is your question? All you've stated is things you want. What have you attempted to achieve this goal so far?

Comment: i tried to put it in code but it showed a weird problem. also, i added my try too :)